# Trying using lag function inside case_when in a cumulative operation in R. Loop necessary?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column combining mutate() and case_when() functions from dplyr. Starting from a string with code "start", I need to subtract to it another string when code is "fi" or add one when code is "fu", in a cumulative operation. The result of the previous application of the function should be used as argument in the next one when codes are "fi" or "fu". I tried using lag() in order to subtract/add a string to the above result. I think the error I get is because the new column is not yet an object I can refer to in the case_when() function.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(code = c("start","fi","fu","fi","start","fi","start","fu"),
             id = c("x,y,", "y,", "z,p,", "p,", "z,p,", "p,", "x,y,z,", "p,q,"))

# A tibble: 8 × 2
  code  id    
  <chr> <chr> 
1 start x,y   
2 fi    y,    
3 fu    z,p,  
4 fi    p,    
5 start z,p,  
6 fi    p,    
7 start x,y,z,
8 fu    p,q, 

# the desired output is

  code  id    id2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 start x,y   x,y,
2 fi    y,    x,
3 fu    z,p,  x,z,p,
4 fi    p,    x,z,
5 start z,p,  z,p,
6 fi    p,    z,
7 start x,z,  x,z,
8 fu    p,q,  x,z,p,q,

# I tried this

df %>% mutate(id2 = case_when(code == "start" ~ id,
                              code == "fu" ~ paste0(lag(id2,1), id),
                              code == "fi" ~ str_replace_all(lag(id2,1), id, "")

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `id2 = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! object 'id2' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`purrr::accumulate2()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/accumulate.html). `accumulate()` applies a function along a vector, with the result of each "step" available as input for the next "step." `accumulate2()` does the same but with two input vectors (e.g., your `code` and `id` columns).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id2 = unlist(accumulate2(
    id, 
    code[-1],
    \(id2, id, code) case_when(
      code == "start" ~ id,
      code == "fu" ~ paste0(id2, id),
      code == "fi" ~ str_remove_all(id2, id)
    )
  )))
```

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  code  id     id2      
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>     
1 start x,y,   x,y,      
2 fi    y,     x,        
3 fu    z,p,   x,z,p,    
4 fi    p,     x,z,      
5 start z,p,   z,p,      
6 fi    p,     z,        
7 start x,y,z, x,y,z,    
8 fu    p,q,   x,y,z,p,q,
```

You need to use `unlist()` (or `as.character()`) because `accumulate2()` returns a list. And you need to pass `code[-1]` rather than just `code` because `accumulate2()` expects the second vector to be one shorter than the first vector.